# Turning an array indicating the topics present in a document into a tuple enumerating the topics

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples, topic-modeling

The title of this might be a bit confusing so let me clarify: I am currently using LDA (with sklearn package) to generate the main topics of a list of documents. After implementing it, I can access the output like this

```
-input: lda_cv_output[0]
-output: 
array([0.00131579, 0.00131579, 0.00131579, 0.81370014, 0.00131579,
       0.00131579, 0.00131579, 0.00131579, 0.00131579, 0.00131579,
       0.16261565, 0.00131579, 0.00131579, 0.00131579, 0.00131579,
       0.00131579, 0.00131579, 0.00131579, 0.00131579, 0.00131579])
```

in order to see from all the 20 generated topics, their relevance for the first document.

What I wanted to get is something along the lines of

```
[(1, 0.00131579),(2, 0.00131579),(3, 0.00131579),(4, 0.81370014),(5, 0.00131579),(6, 0.00131579),(7, 0.00131579),(8, 0.00131579),(9, 0.00131579),(10, 0.00131579),(11, 0.16261565),(12, 0.00131579),(13, 0.00131579),(14, 0.00131579),(15, 0.00131579),(16, 0.00131579),(17, 0.00131579),(18, 0.00131579),(19, 0.00131579),(20, 0.00131579)]
```

so I can easily visualise each topic's relevance to the document.

However, I am not sure how to go about it. Could anyone help me with a quick and easy way to do it?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but should produce a list of the format specified, assigned to the output_lst variable. The enumerate() function takes a list and when you iterate over it returns each element paired with its index, starting at 0. Thus, i+1 so that your list starts at 1.

```
output_lst = [(i+1,x) for i,x in enumerate(lda_cv_output[0])]
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you for your explanation! I tried to apply this to all the docs like this :

`for doc in range(20):
    output_lst = [(i+1,x) for i,x in enumerate(lda_cv_output[doc])]`
but it's not giving me the correct output. Do you have an idea why it doesn't work and how I could generalise it for all the docs?

Comment: The output_lst variable will be overwritten for each document when doing it this way, so likely when you finish output_lst will contain the values for just the final doc. If you want to store all of the values you need to create the array beforehand (output_lst = []) and then append to it for each doc (output_lst.append([(i+1,x) for i,x in enumerate(lda_cv_output[doc])]) inside your for loop.

Comment: Alternatively, a more concise way of producing the same output is the following nested list comprehension: `output_lst = [[(i+1,x) for i,x in enumerate(lda_cv_output[doc])] for doc in range(20)]`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It totally helped me understand this better!! Have a nice day!